# Django - Get a single timestamp per foreign key ID (MySQL)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Im having trouble getting only a single record per foreign key ID on the below model, I have tried this query, but it doesnt seem to be doing anything at all currently

I have used a RAW query which works, but I can't use a filter on it. ive also created a list and removed duplicates from the QuerySet but again I can't filter it because its a list

Query:

```
queryset = BGPData.objects.annotate(max_timestamp=Max('timestamp')).filter(timestamp=F('max_timestamp')).select_related(
    'device_circuit_subnet__subnet',
    'device_circuit_subnet__device',
    'device_circuit_subnet__circuit',
    'device_circuit_subnet__device__site',
    )
```

Model:

```
class BGPData(models.Model):
    device_circuit_subnet = models.ForeignKey(DeviceCircuitSubnets, verbose_name="Device", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bgp_peer_as = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='BGP Peer AS', blank=True, null=True)
    bgp_session = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='BGP Session', blank=True, null=True)
    bgp_routes = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='BGP Routes Received', blank=True, null=True)
    service_status = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Service Status', blank=True, null=True)  
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

Sample Data im testing with (printed as a dict), there should only be one record for "device_circuit_subnet_id" : "10", the one which is newest.

I would like the latest record per device_circuit_subnet_id, so the query should return 3 results instead of 4, as there are 2 items with the same device_circuit_subnet_id.

ive read that distinct is used for this but were running MySQL, is there another way?

Thanks

```
[{
        "id": 4,
        "device_circuit_subnet_id" : "10",
        "hostname": "EDGE",
        "circuit_name": "MPLS",
        "subnet": "172.1.1.1",
        "subnet_mask": "/30",
        "bgp_session": "1w2d",
        "bgp_routes": "377",
        "bgp_peer_as": "1",
        "service_status": "Up",
        "timestamp": "2019-11-18 16:16:17"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "device_circuit_subnet_id" : "11",
        "hostname": "INT-GW",
        "subnet": "1.1.1.1",
        "subnet_mask": "/24",
        "bgp_session": null,
        "bgp_routes": null,
        "bgp_peer_as": null,
        "service_status": "unknown",
        "timestamp": "2019-08-07 14:46:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "hostname": "EDGE",
        "device_circuit_subnet_id" : "20",
        "circuit_name": "MPLS 02",
        "subnet": "172.2.1.1",
        "subnet_mask": "/30",
        "bgp_session": null,
        "bgp_routes": null,
        "bgp_peer_as": null,
        "service_status": "unknown",
        "timestamp": "2019-11-15 16:18:30"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "hostname": "EDGE",
        "device_circuit_subnet_id" : "10",
        "circuit_name": "MPLS",
        "subnet": "172.1.1.1",
        "subnet_mask": "/30",
        "bgp_session": "1w3d",
        "bgp_routes": "385",
        "bgp_peer_as": "1",
        "service_status": "Up",
        "timestamp": "2019-11-18 16:16:44"
    }
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but you could move to PostgreSQL and then use `.order_by('-timestamp').distinct('device_circuit_subnet')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
from django.db.models import Max, F

max_timestamp = Max('device_circuit_subnet__bgpdata__timestamp')
result = BGPData.objects.annotate(ts=max_timestamp).filter(timestamp=F('ts')).select_related(...)
```

I'm not sure about the ***performance*** of this query, but it will work :) :)

Comment: won't this just get a single record? Im hoping to get a single record per device_circuit_subnet_id, so in the data above there are 3 unique device_circuit_subnet_id's. I would like to get the newest record of each unique id

Comment: The **`result`** will be a QuerySet having **`N`** records, where **`N`** is the total number of *unique* value of **`device_circuit_subnet`**

Comment: Have you run the snippet on your environment? Is there any problem?

Comment: I had to change my environment, I will be changing it again so I can test this soon, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Django querysets are evaluated in a lazy fashion. As such, this query will only fetch one record from the database. The ordering on timestamp is in descending order due to the `-` prefix, so the latest timestamp value will be the first record.

```
queryset = BGPData.objects.all().order_by(
    #prefix field name to order by with `-` to use Descending order
    '-timestamp'
).select_related(
    'device_circuit_subnet__subnet',
    'device_circuit_subnet__device',
    'device_circuit_subnet__circuit',
    'device_circuit_subnet__device__site',
)[0]
```

Comment: sorry, perhaps I explained incorrectly, this will only get me one record, I would like the latest record per device_circuit_subnet_id, so the query should return 3 results instead of 4, as there are 2 items with the same device_circuit_subnet_id